# How to change body background with image from img element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some images which are hidden, the markup is

```
<div class="images hide">
    <img id="barber" class="barber-image" src="../../Content/images/chosing_business_role/barberShopBackground.jpg" />
    <img id="beauty" src="../../Content/images/background_image.png" />
</div>
```

And i need to change body background with the first one of them when images loaded, but without new request to server for that image. How can i do that? Thanks.

Comment: Just use javascript to exchange the background image with the first image. Since the image has just been loaded, there won't be an extra request, the data should come from the browser's cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#barber').on('load', changeBodyBackground);
// when image loads, call function

....

function changeBodyBackground(e){
  $('body').css('background-image', $(this).attr('src'));
  // set background-image property for body
}
```

Comment: @Newinjava, it's working. I think browser cares about caching images. In my case, I have 12 large images(img tags) in hidden div element and once its all loaded when i change background of the body there is no additional request to server. I'm using Chrome now.

Comment: I was just curious about the syntax. because that syntax didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src = "jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .hide{display:none;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="images hide">
        <img id="barber" class="barber-image" src="1.jpg" />
            <img id="beauty" src="2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('body').css('background','url('+$('#barber').attr('src')+')');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

you can also use background-image

```
$('body').css('background-image','url('+$('#barber').attr('src')+')');
```